# How to prevent whitespace cleanup at point?

Tags: hooks, whitespace, point

I have hooked `whitespace-cleanup` to `before-save-hook` and there is a timer to  auto save buffer every  5 seconds.

When i am  typing something, or coding in python, I stop once in a while and buffer will be whitespace cleaned.

So this text

```
Emacs  is |
```

becomes

```
Emacs is|
```

and

```
def foo():
     x = 1
     |
```

becomes

```
def foo():
     x = 1
|
```

It is quite annoying to type all  that whitespaces again and again.  How can i prevent whitespace cleanup at point but still clean  whitespace in the remaining buffer?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a better method to delete trailing whitespace at the end of the buffer when manually saving, instead of using `whitespace-cleanup`?  If so, stop using `whitespace-cleanup` . . . . http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Useless-Whitespace.html and see also http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeletingWhitespace

Comment: I use `editorconfig` to get rid of trailing whitespace, among other things. https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-emacs#readme I am not sure if it will have the same problem (I haven't looked into what it hooks into to do cleanup - it has always just worked in the background for me, keeping my files in a state that I like), but it is generally a very useful tool.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own whitespace-cleanup function which does not clean up the current line, e.g.:

```
(defun white-space-cleanup-without-current-line ()
  (interactive)
  (whitespace-cleanup-region (point-min) (line-beginning-position))
  (whitespace-cleanup-region (line-end-position) (point-max)))
```

and use it for the save hook.

Comment: Will this work if there are multiple empty lines before and after point?